# "Windows is preparing your computer for first use" message appears on each boot

Tags: windows-7, boot

I got a new laptop today, a Toshiba with Windows 7 installed on it. Once all the Toshiba setup stuff had run I did the usual windows updates and played with it a little etc. Every time I boot it though, I get the same message, that Windows is preparing for it

Comment: Sounds like an installer crashed and didn't toggle the flag for first boot...can't find it at the moment but it's a dropped file or a regkey i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the installation didn't actually complete properly. Probably because I was (stupidly) installing and uninstalling stuff (norton) while the rest of the installation was actually happening. Turning off my PC and holding 0 while turning on the power launched the recovery mode and I simply ran the setup again without touching anything.

The installation completed properly and the machine now runs great.

Comment: Holding 0 ? thats a new one on me.

Comment: I have a new Toshiba Satellite. Their phone support FAQ told me about it.